# Return selected images

Tags: javascript, html, input, selection

I have an HTML code. 
There must be 2 questions each of them suggest 4 answers which are images. How can I return in result selected images  with javascript?

```
<div class="quest">
        <div class="answer">
            <input type="radio"  value="car1"  class="inputimg"/>
            <label for="car1">
                <img src="spare.png">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="answer">
            <input type="radio"  value="car2"  class="inputimg" />
            <label for="car2">              
                <img src="spare.png">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="answer">
            <input type="radio"  value="car3"  class="inputimg" />
            <label for="car3">
                <img src="spare.png">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="answer">
            <input type="radio"  value="car4"  class="inputimg" />
            <label for="car4">
                <img src="spare.png">
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please explain what is your "result"

Comment: selected radio can be extracted by querying form ,refer this example https://jsfiddle.net/api/mdn/  . ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio

Comment: pure js way  , `document.querySelector('input[name="contact"]:checked').value;` .

if jquery is option, then try this `$("input[name=rate]:checked").val()`

Comment: Also,add a `name` attribute to all the radio buttons with same name value, otherwise each radio button would work as individually and not as a single set

Comment: result shoud be 2 selected images, for example, a person choose car1 image for the first questione and car5 for the second. so, in result both of the selected images must appear as a conclusion maybe in new div, but not in alert or smth, the problem for me is return not just value, but image as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below code ,

When you click on the image it will alert the value of the corresponding radio button

```js
/* using jquery*/

function test(dhis){
  var val=dhis.attr('src');
  $('#displayimg').append(' <img src="'+val+'">')
}

/* using javascript*/

function test1(dhis){
  var val=dhis.getAttribute('src');
  var div = document.getElementById('displayimg');
  div.innerHTML +=' <img src="'+val+'">'
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quest">
            <div class="answer">
                <input type="radio"  value="car1"  class="inputimg" name="test" id="car1"/>
                <label for="car1" >
                    <img src="spare.png" onclick="test($(this));test1(this)">
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="answer">
                <input type="radio"  name="test" value="car2"  class="inputimg" id="car2" />
                <label for="car2" >              
                    <img src="spare.png" onclick="test($(this));test1(this)">
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="answer">
                <input type="radio" name="test" value="car3"  class="inputimg" id="car3"/>
                <label for="car3">
                    <img src="spare.png" onclick="test($(this));test1(this)">
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="answer">
                <input type="radio" name="test"  value="car4"  class="inputimg"id="car4" />
                <label for="car4">
                    <img src="spare.png" onclick="test($(this));test1(this)">
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="displayimg">
        </div>
```

Comment: problem is that I need this 2 selected images appear in new div, not alert values

Comment: I have just one more question on this. divs "answer" have an overlay effect on them, so I can't click on image. I put the onclick function on div and replaced getAttribute with getElementsByTagName('img') but they didn't appear in innerHTML